# How to force TinyMCE to use flash youtube embed instead of iframe?

Tags: flash, iframe, youtube, tinymce

I am using TinyMCE 3.4.9 and am trying to force the media plugin to always use the Flash embedding instead of iFrame embedding.

For security reasons, I don't want to allow any embedding of iFrames.

I have formatted the URL manually to get a Flash embed object instead of the iFrame object.

IE-

- Flash embed: http://www.youtube.com/v/fWNaR-rxAic
- iFrame embed:
  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fWNaR-rxAic

Is there a way to do one of the two:

1. Onchange of the embed file/URL field, modify the URL so that the Flash object will be embedded by default. (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fWNaR-rxAic would be converted to http://www.youtube.com/v/fWNaR-rxAic)
2. Change the call to youtube so that youtube will return the Flash object instead of the iFrame.

My TinyMCE initialization code is:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    tinyMCE.init(
        {
            paste_remove_styles : true,
            gecko_spellcheck : true,
            theme_advanced_font_sizes : "1,2,3,4,5",
            extended_valid_elements:"script[charset|defer|language|src|type]",
            theme : "advanced",
            mode: "exact",
            plugins: "inlinepopups,emotions,searchreplace,paste,media",
            elements : "blogcontent",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
            theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,sub,sup,|,fontselect,fontsizeselect,forecolor,|,link,unlink,|,backcolor",
            theme_advanced_buttons2 : "justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,|,search,replace,|,image,charmap,emotions, media,|,undo,redo",
            theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
            theme_advanced_resize_horizontal : false,
            theme_advanced_resizing : false,
            file_browser_callback : 'file_browser',
            relative_urls : false,
            remove_script_host : false,
            paste_retain_style_properties : "font-size,color,font-family,background-color",
            setup : 
                function(ed)
                {
                    ed.onKeyUp.add(
                        function(ed, e)
                        {
                            ed.nodeChanged();
                        }
                    );
                }
        }
    );

</script>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I haven't found a way to force flash embedding of youtube videos I created a work around for the iframe security problem.

I have added the iframe to the allowed tags list and on display of the content to the user after saving, I have a whitelist filter applied to any iframes that pulls out any iframes that don't have a src in the whitelist.

```
function filterIframeBySource($text, $allowed_sources)
{
    // regex to retrieve just the iframes
    $regex      = '/<iframe[0-9a-zA-Z \.\/=>:\-"]*<\/iframe>/';
    $matches    = array();
    $reg_pos    = preg_match($regex, $text, $matches);

    // loop through each match and check the src for that iframe
    $src_expression = '/ src="http:\/\/('.str_replace('.', '\.', implode('|', $allowed_sources)).')[0-9a-zA-Z\/-]*" /';
    foreach($matches as $match)
    {
        $src_pos    = preg_match($src_expression, $match);

        if($src_pos !== false && $src_pos === 0)
            $text   = str_replace($match, '[Removed iFrame]', $text);
    }
    return $text;
}
```

Hope this helps.